# Java Date instances issue

Tags: java, date

I got the following in the body of the code:

```
public String getStartDate() {
    return (new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(startDate));
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

and startDate is initiated as Date startDate;
 When I use the set startdate method, I am setting the value of this instance to the value of the object retrieved from database..

```
 setStartDate(rsvIns.startDate);
```

Now the problem is here when I try to see if the startDate is equal to TodayDate,

```
            Date todayDate = new Date();
            if(startDate.equals(todayDate))
            {
                changeStatus(requestID, "Active");
            }else{
                //update status if others approved
                changeStatus(requestID, "Approved");
            }
```

I whenever it comes to the equals line it throws error and just doesn't execute the if or else part, hence the statement is never executed. Any idea why this could be happening?
Thanks,

Comment: Care to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Are you sure startDate is not null?

Comment: About the only thing I see on that line that would throw is if startDate is null, but you should wrap it in a try catch and print or log the exception so you can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @nolt2232 am sure it isn't because it is used to display in the form the date which is showing. Is there any other error in syntax that I am overlooking?

Comment: @BrianRoach hmmm sorry for not being so clear, but the I misused the word error for no action performed :)

Comment: where are you used this date, web or application?

Comment: web mate i am using JSF on a page but doesn't matter as this backing bean

Comment: How do you know that neither `if` nor `else` code-blocks are executed? Maybe the `changeStatus(...)` method isn't working properly. Try to put breakpoints inside both blocks, or debug it step-by-step.

Comment: @yair because when I put the changeStatus() without condition it works

Comment: I can't say that's an ultimate proof but you should debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems from the code snippets you provided:

1. Date todayDate = new Date() object contains in information on Hour, Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds. If you compare it to a date created from a "dd/MM/yyyy" string you will have a problem caused by the time component of the Date object.
2. getStartDate() returns a String object. If that value is assigned to the startDate variable from the if statement, then on equals() call with a Date object parameter value the result will be false regardless of the startDate and parameter value, because the classes do not match.

If you get into situations like this and you do not see the answer, copy the code into a small program and debug trace it, look at the values of the objects. Trace into java code.

I have seen many times java developers with years of experience trip on the time component of Date object. They even clear the Hour, Minutes and Seconds and forget about the Milliseconds component.

Comment: Thanks the issue is returning string and comparing that with Date type. Thanks again for being the most helpful.